# Golang DDD implementation of dependent modules

Tags: go, interface, architecture, domain-driven-design

I'm trying to implement DDD architecture to my application modules and get stuck with a problem of storing similar(depending) structures between them.

In the first package I store everything that is related to entity **People**: Services(Repositories), Controllers, Models, etc...

In the second package I store everything that is related to another entity **Apartments**: Services(Repositories), Controllers, Models, etc...

Each **Apartment** can contain multiple **Tenants** which are stored in database as the same structure as **People**.

Some **Apartment** package services should be able to call methods like get/update/... **Tenants**. I would gladly not re-implement these actions and use them from the implementations in the **People** package *PeopleService*, but that service returns **People** entity, not the **Tenant**.

Should I create additional structure (copy-paste whole source code) of **People** into the **Apartment** package, call it **Tenant** and convert return types of *PeopleService* to it?

Or is there another way to do it?

Also, where should I store interfaces of services/repositories(interfaces with CRUD-like methods) of concrete entity? Should interface *PeopleService* be both in **People** and **Apartment** packages?

Thanks.

Comment: DDD is not an architecture. DDD has nothing to do with CRUD. If you can just copy-paste code across entities and services you are dealing with CRUD and you do not need DDD and a domain model at all. Get a CRUD application generator and be done with this.

Answer (score 6):

There could be different approaches and frankly the question probably should be closed as too broad & opinion based.

I probably would do it this way:

1. Decouple all linked models in a separate packages `models`.
2. Use composition for People->Tenants, e.g.

   `type Person { Name string }
   type Tenant struct { Person }`
3. Regards People<->Apartments - create a package `tenants` that will operate with models & services of people & apartments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah, question may be really too general. I just think that decoupling models to the separate package doesn't seem like DDD-way... I have already used composition, but it didn't help with code-redundancy: Person model should be both in Apartment and Tenant packages. Separating Tenants to the another package is nice solution, will try it for sure, it can add additional fields to the Person (like 'his apartment') making it Tenant, but can't do the same for the Apartment (like 'its tenants') because for Apartment operations we use Apartment package.

Comment: You can't have both independence and bi-directional awareness.

There is probably no need for an apartment to know anything about tenants but just list of ids. Then you can do something `tenants.GetByIDs(apartment.CurrentTenantIDs)`.

An upvote for an answer is as good as "thank you" ;)